# Copying data from byte[] to struct using pointers in C#

Tags: c#

I have a byte array (from a socket) that I would like to copy into a struct.
I have moved away from using Marshal.Copy as this, to my understanding, allocates managed memory and not stack memory. (The data comes at a rather fast rate and have a short lifespan before being saved to disk, so I would like to avoid creating a lot of short lived managed objects.)

How can I copy, byte by byte, from the byte[] into the struct?

Comment: You mean heap memory instead of managed memory? What makes you think it is bad to create lots of short lived objects on the heap?

Comment: Short-lived objects are actually *insanely* cheap - GEN0 is cheap to flush

Comment: I mean stack memory instead of heap. It's not necessarily bad, but there will be some overhead in allocating and deallocating struct or classes on the heap (the gc is involved).

Comment: The fact that your question does not contain the phrase "I have profiled and found this and that about the GC" or "GC Performance Counters" or "Gen2" makes me 95% confident that you don't have any problem with a lot of short lived objects on the heap.

Comment: @MarcGravell can you give a reference to this statement? Does the cost (or lack cost) scale well with the number of objects?

Comment: @albin-sunnanbo True, I have not done that yet. But when I do, I would like to compare to the byte-by-byte unsafe stack method. Which brings me back to my question. How is that accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

Final code looks like this:

```
unsafe void CastData(out SomeStructure someStruct, byte[] bytes)
{
    fixed (byte* pSource = bytes)
    {
        fixed (SomeStructure* pDest = &someStruct)
        {
            *pDest = *((SomeStructure*)pSource);
        }
    }
}
```

To my understanding, this should be completely deterministic and "safe".

Assuming that it is, then I found the unsafe method to be approx. 31 times faster than the method shown at (e.g.) http://thecodeisart.blogspot.com/2008/11/with-this-class-you-can-easy-convert.html